# Single sign on across different web browsers

Tags: c#, authentication, single-sign-on

I'm trying to create a web app (website 1) housed inside a windows web browser control. Links in this web app will redirect to another website (website 2) and open in the user's default browser. So the problem I have the windows app housing website 1 is unable to communicate with website 2. Website 1 and website 2 can potentially share the same database.

Is it possible to implement a type of single sign on that I can some how persist across different browsers?

Comment: Use cookies for this scenario

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with using cross browser cookies. (e.g. Flash cookies are cross browser)
http://www.nuff-respec.com/technology/cross-browser-cookies-with-flash
http://www.sajithmr.me/cross-browser-cookies/
http://www.ts0.com/2007/12/cross-browser-cookies.asp
http://www.jon-reed.co.uk/2010/06/28/track-web-visitors-using-cross-browser-cookies-that-won%E2%80%99t-be-deleted/